# APSR template problem

Tags: templates

I am preparing a submission to American Political Science Review and intend to use the tex template available at Overleaf.com.

I am using Miktex 2.9 and TexWork 0.6.2 (OS Win10).

The template is the following:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Please note that whilst this template provides a 
% preview of the typeset manuscript for submission, it 
% will not necessarily be the final publication layout.
%
%% Document class options: (**...** are defaults)
%  - bibtex: Uses bibtex+natbib, chicago.bst 
%  - biblatex: Uses biblatex-chicago
%      You MUST select one of the above two options, depending
%      on whether you prefer bibtex or biblatex. This template
%      contains code that uses bibtex.
%  - twocolumn: Switch to two column for main text
%  - singlespace/onehalfspace/**doublespace**: 
%         changes line spacing for main text
%  - **blind**/nonblind: Anonymises authors 
%         and affiliations, or not
%  - autowc: Automatically inserts a word count
%         after the abstract, using texcount. 
%         The abstract is ignored. 
%         NOTE THAT THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF YOU HAVE  
%         INSTALLED TEXCOUNT, AND HAVE ENABLED --shell-escape
%         OR --enable-write18. (These will work on Overleaf.)
%         If you get an error about "texcount not found", delete
%         the autowc option, and manually specify the wordcount 
%         with \totalwordcount{xxx}.
%%% autowc may cause longer compilation time. You can 
%%% disable it first while actively editing, and only
%%% enable it when you're ready to take stock and check
%%% on your work.
\documentclass[bibtex]{apsr_submission}
% \totalwordcount{500}

%% Example alternative options with everything the opposite of the above: (DO NOT USE AUTOWC WITH BIBLATEX; the word count will be greatly over-reported)
% \documentclass[biblatex,nonblind,singlespace,twocolumn]{apsr_submission}

\title{American Political Science Review \emph{(APSR)} Submission Template}

% The custom \author command takes THREE arguments:
% #1 = Author name
% #2 = Affiliation name
% #3 = Brief author profile, or anything that you'd usually put in a \thanks. Leave blank {} if there's nothing to be said.
\author{Author One}
       {Affiliation A}
       {Author One is PhD Candidate, ABC Department, Affiliation A, 12345 NY. (a.1@example.edu)}

\author{Author Two}
       {Affiliation C}
       {Author Two is Assistant Professor, Faculty of Z, Affiliation B, 42813. Corresponding Author (a.2@acme.edu) Additional notes about Author Two.}

\author{Author Three}
       {Affiliation B}
       {Author Three is ...}

%% Any other acknowledgements or author notes
\thanks{The authors thank...}

%% These are used for the headers
\runningtitle{APSR Submission Template}
\runningauthor{Author One, Author Two, and Author Three} % 4 + Authors, Author One et al. 

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% If you are using a custom figure or table environment from a package and it's not getting framed, add \makeframedenv{MyFigure} in the preamble, where the custom figure environment is \begin{MyFigure}...\end{MyFigure}.
%% Currently table, table*, figure, figure*, longtable, supertabular, sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure will be automatically framed.

%% Handy for setting wide tables/figures in landscape
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%% Recent LaTeX distributions should be able to automatically convert .eps to .pdf; but if this isn't happening, try loading the epstopdf package manually
% \usepackage{epstopdf}

%% Just to add some dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% Use \addbibresource{...} if using BibLaTeX
% \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

%%% DO NOT REMOVE THESE LINES. For automatic word count.
%TC:ignore
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
Your abstract. It should be at least three lines long to accommodate the dropped-cap. \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
%%% DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. For automatic word count.
%TC:endignore

\section{Introduction}

\dropcap{Thanks} for using Overleaf to write your article. Your introduction goes here! Do make sure the first paragraph here is at least three lines long, to accommodate the dropped-cap. Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.

Here's a second paragraph of extra text, to test paragraph indents.

\section{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
\label{sec:examples}

Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use \verb|\ref| and \verb|\label| commands for cross-references.

\subsection{Figures and Tables}

Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table \ref{tab:widgets}, for example. \href{http://tablesgenerator.com}{TablesGenerator.com} is a handy tool for designing tables and generating the  LaTeX code, which you can copy and paste into your article here.

You can upload a figure (JPG, PNG or PDF) using the PROJECT menu (Files\ldots > Add files). To include it in your document, use the \verb|graphicx| package and the \verb|\includegraphics| command as in the code for Figure \ref{fig:view}. 

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\caption{An example table}
\label{tab:widgets}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Item & Quantity \\\midrule
Widgets & 42 \\
Gadgets & 13
\end{tabular}
\floatnote{This is a note for this table.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{A figure example.}
\label{fig:view}

\floatnote{This is a note for this figure.}
\end{figure}


Notes can be added to the bottom of figures and tables using the \verb|\floatnote| command.


\begin{table*}
\caption{Automobile Land Speed Records (GR 5-10).}
\label{tab:wide}

\begin{tabular}{l l l l r}
Speed (mph) & Driver          & Car                        & Engine    & Date     \\
\midrule
407.447     & Craig Breedlove & Spirit of America          & GE J47    & 8/5/63   \\
413.199     & Tom Green       & Wingfoot Express           & WE J46    & 10/2/64  \\
434.22      & Art Arfons      & Green Monster              & GE J79    & 10/5/64  \\
468.719     & Craig Breedlove & Spirit of America          & GE J79    & 10/13/64 \\
526.277     & Craig Breedlove & Spirit of America          & GE J79    & 10/15/65 \\
536.712     & Art Arfons      & Green Monster              & GE J79    & 10/27/65 \\
555.127     & Craig Breedlove & Spirit of America, Sonic 1 & GE J79    & 11/2/65  \\
576.553     & Art Arfons      & Green Monster              & GE J79    & 11/7/65  \\
600.601     & Craig Breedlove & Spirit of America, Sonic 1 & GE J79    & 11/15/65 \\
622.407     & Gary Gabelich   & Blue Flame                 & Rocket    & 10/23/70 \\
633.468     & Richard Noble   & Thrust 2                   & RR RG 146 & 10/4/83  \\
763.035     & Andy Green      & Thrust SSC                 & RR Spey   & 10/15/97\\
\end{tabular}

\floatnote{\url{https://www.sedl.org/afterschool/toolkits/science/pdf/ast_sci_data_tables_sample.pdf}}

\end{table*}

For wide, double-column figures and tables, use the \verb|figure*| (Figure \ref{fig:wide}) or \verb|table*| (Table \ref{tab:wide}) starred environments. Landscaped figures and tables can be obtained using the \texttt{sidewaysfigure} and \texttt{sidewaysfigure} commands from the \texttt{rotating} package. Alternatively, you can use the \texttt{landscape} environment from the \texttt{pdflscape} package.

Multi-page tables can be created using the \texttt{longtable} and \texttt{supertabular} packages, though note that \texttt{longtable}s cannot be used in two-column documents.\footnote{This is an example footnote. \lipsum[1]}


Currently \texttt{table}, \texttt{table*}, \texttt{figure}, \texttt{figure*}, \texttt{longtable}, \texttt{supertabular}, \texttt{sidewaystable} and \texttt{sidewaysfigure} will be automatically framed.

If you are using a custom figure or table environment from a package (e.g.~a \texttt{MyFigure} environment) and it's not getting framed, add \verb|\makeframedenv{MyFigure}| in the preamble. 

\subsection{Lists and Quotations}

You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

\begin{enumerate}
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{enumerate}

\dots or bullet points \dots

\begin{itemize} 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{itemize}

\dots or with words and descriptions \dots

\begin{description}
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Concept] Explanation
\item[Idea] Text
\end{description}

An example quotation:

\begin{quoting}
This is a sample quotation text. This is a sample quotation text. This is a sample quotation text.
\end{quoting}

(This is some filler text.) \lipsum[2]

\subsection{Citations}

\LaTeX{} formats citations and references automatically using the bibliography records in your .bib file, which you can edit via the project menu. Use the \verb|\citep| command for a citation in parentheses \citep{greenwade93}, or  \verb|\citet| for a text citation: \citet{greenwade93}. Multiple citations can be given as \citep{greenwade93,knuth1984texbook}.

If your manuscript is accepted, the APSR production team will re-format the references for publication. \emph{It is not necessary to format the reference list yourself to mirror the final published form.}

\subsubsection{Using bibtex} Pass the \texttt{bibtex} option to the \verb|\documentclass| declaration, then specify your \texttt{.bib} file with \verb|\bibliography{sample}| (the extension is unnecessary) near the end of your manuscript, where you want the references list to appear.

\subsubsection{Using biblatex} Pass the \texttt{biblatex} option to the \verb|\documentclass| declaration, then specify your \texttt{.bib} file name in the \emph{preamble}: \verb|\addbibresources{sample.bib}| (the extension is necessary). Write \verb|\printbibliography| near the end of your manuscript where you want the references to appear.

Note that you may want to remove the \texttt{autowc} (automatic word count) document class option, if you are using \texttt{biblatex}. There have been reports of texcount over-reporting word counts when authors use \texttt{biblatex}, due to the database nature of \texttt{.bbl} files produced by \texttt{biblatex}. For more information, see \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110902/226}.

\subsection{Mathematics}

\LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics:

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:CLT}
S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
      = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i
\end{equation}
denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\caption{A wide figure}\label{fig:wide}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\end{figure*}

\section{Level 1 heading}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Level 2 Heading}

\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Level 3 Heading}

\lipsum[4]
\input{tableex2}

%% Use \bibliography{...} if using BibTeX
\bibliography{sample}

%TC:subst \printbibliography \bibliography
%TC:macro \field [0,1]
%TC:macro \name [0,0,0,1]
%TC:macro \list [0,0,1]
%% Use \printbibliography if using BibLaTeX
% \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, I got an error message, saying that apsr_submission.cls is missing. I was able to find it. It looks like:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% apsr_submission.cls, v1.1, 2017/12/06
% Developed by Overleaf
% 
% This class file enables authors to prepare 
% manuscripts for submission to APSR.
%
% v1.01: corrected ASPR typos to APSR
% v1.1: Uses chicago-apsr.bst that doesn't shorten first names
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{apsr_submission}[2017/12/06 v1.1]

\newif\if@biblatex
\newif\if@blind
\newif\if@twocol
\newif\if@onehalfspace
\newif\if@doublespace
\newif\if@extracover
\newif\if@autowc
\DeclareOption{biblatex}{\@biblatextrue}
\DeclareOption{bibtex}{\@biblatexfalse}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocoltrue}
\DeclareOption{blind}{\@blindtrue}
\DeclareOption{nonblind}{\@blindfalse}
\DeclareOption{singlespace}{\@onehalfspacefalse\@doublespacefalse}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspace}{\@onehalfspacetrue\@doublespacefalse}
\DeclareOption{doublespace}{\@onehalfspacefalse\@doublespacetrue}
\DeclareOption{autowc}{\@autowctrue}
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@extracovertrue}
\ExecuteOptions{blind,doublespace}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twoside,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Ignoring empty anchor}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Rerun to get}
\WarningFilter*{microtype}{Unknown slot number of character}

%% Language and font encodings
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex,ifpdf}
\ifxetex\else
  \ifluatex\else
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi\fi
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

%% Sets page size and margins
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.2cm,left=2.1cm,right=2.5cm,columnsep=0.65cm,footskip=2.5\baselineskip,headsep=1.5\baselineskip]{geometry}


%% Front matters
\def\@authorlist{}
\def\@authorinfo{}
\def\@authorlistblind{}
\def\@authorinfoblind{}
\def\@runningauthor{}
\def\@runningtitle{}
\def\@journalname{American Political Science Review}
\def\@publishername{American Political Science Association}
\def\@publishedyear{\the\year}

\renewcommand{\author}[3]{%
  \appto{\@authorlist}{%
    {\noindent\Large%
      \ifxetex\MakeUppercase{#1}%
      \else\ifpdf
        \textls[80]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
          \else\MakeUppercase{#1}%
      \fi\fi%
    }\hspace{1em}%
    {\itshape\large #2}\par\vskip3pt}%
    \authorinfo{#3\par}
}

\RequirePackage[style]{abstract}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{tikz,pgffor}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.25em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\appto{\LettrineFontHook}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\upshape}
\renewcommand{\LettrineSecondString}{l}
\newcommand{\dropcap}[2][]{\lettrine[#1] #2}

\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{2em}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{2em}
\setlength{\absparindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\itshape\noindent\dropcap[findent=0.5em]}

\let\maketitle\relax

\newcommand{\authorinfo}[1]{\appto{\@authorinfo}{#1}}
\let\thanks\authorinfo
\newcommand{\runningauthor}[1]{\def\@runningauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\runningtitle}[1]{\def\@runningtitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\publishedyear}[1]{\def\@publishedyear{#1}}

\RequirePackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.25em}
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\small}
\if@doublespace
  \appto{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}
\fi
\if@onehalfspace
  \appto{\footnotelayout}{\onehalfspacing}
\fi

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
  {\fontfamily{qhvc}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont\raggedright\@title\par\vskip3pt}
  {\@authorlist\par}
}

\if@blind
  \newcommand{\@anonymizeauthors}{
    \def\@authorlistblind{}
    \def\@authorinfoblind{}
    \patchcmd{\author}{\@authorlist}{\@authorlistblind}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\authorinfo}{\@authorinfo}{\@authorinfoblind}{}{}
    \author{Anonymised Author(s)}{Anonymised Institution(s)}{Anonymised submission.\par\medskip\textbf{This is a  manuscript submitted for review.}}
    \gdef\@runningauthor{Anonymised Author(s)}
    \let\@authorlist\@authorlistblind
    \let\@authorinfo\@authorinfoblind
}
\else
  \let\@anonymizeauthors\relax
\fi

\def\@totalwordcount{0}
\newcommand{\totalwordcount}[1]{%
  %% Only allow total word count to be changed it if it's still 0
  \if@autowc%
    \ClassWarning{apsr_submission.cls}{\string\totalwordcount{} is ignored when autowc is active.}
  \else
    \def\@totalwordcount{#1}
  \fi
}
\if@autowc
  \RequirePackage{bashful}
  \newcommand{\@autowordcount}{%
    \def\@totalwordcount{\splice{texcount -1 -sum=1,1,1,0,0,0,0 -merge -incbib -utf8 \jobname.tex}}}%
\else
  \let\@autowordcount\relax
\fi


\NewEnviron{frontmatter}{%
  \def\apsr@frontmatter{
    \@maketitle\BODY%
    \if@autowc\@autowordcount\fi%
    {\centering Word Count: \@totalwordcount\par}%
  }
  \appto{\@authorinfo}{\par\medskip\textbf{This is a  manuscript submitted for review.}\par}
  \if@twocol
    \if@extracover
      \setcounter{page}{0}
      \onecolumn\apsr@frontmatter
      \blfootnote{\hspace*{-\footnotemargin}\@authorinfo}
      \thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
    \fi
    %% Anonymise main text only
    \if@blind\@anonymizeauthors\fi
    \twocolumn[\apsr@frontmatter\bigskip]
  \else
    \if@extracover
      \setcounter{page}{0}
      \apsr@frontmatter
      \blfootnote{\hspace*{-\footnotemargin}\@authorinfo}
      \thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
    \fi
    %% Anonymise main text only
    \if@blind\@anonymizeauthors\fi
    \apsr@frontmatter
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \blfootnote{\hspace*{-\footnotemargin}\@authorinfo}
}{}

\AfterEndEnvironment{frontmatter}{
  \if@onehalfspace\onehalfspacing\fi%
  \if@doublespace\doublespacing\fi%
}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\large\raggedright}{}{0pt}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\bfseries\large\raggedright}{}{0pt}{#1}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\itshape\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{0.25\baselineskip}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{0.25\baselineskip}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep,topsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=2\parindent}

\RequirePackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small,indentfirst=false,begintext={``},endtext={''},vskip=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=\parindent,rightmargin=0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\@runningtitle}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\@runningauthor}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize%
  \textit{Submission to \@journalname}\\[-\baselineskip]%
  \raisebox{-1.25\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{doi:xx.xxxx/xxxxx}
  }
}
\cfoot{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \ifnumodd{\thepage}{%
    \node[transform shape,rotate=90,anchor=north,yshift=-2pt,text=gray!10,font=\scriptsize] at (current page.west) 
  }{%
     \node[transform shape,rotate=-90,anchor=north,yshift=-2pt,text=gray!10,font=\scriptsize] at (current page.east) 
   }
      {\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{APSR Submission Template\hspace{1em}}};
}

%% Easiest way to get framed floats, both single-column and wide
\RequirePackage[framestyle=fbox,framefit=yes,heightadjust=all,framearound=all,font=sf]{floatrow}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\newcommand{\makeframedenv}[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\begin{mdframed}}
  \csappto{end#1}{\end{mdframed}}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{longtable}{
    \floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
    \makeframedenv{longtable}
  }{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{supertabular}{
    \makeframedenv{supertabular}
  }{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{rotating}{
    \makeframedenv{sidewaystable}
    \makeframedenv{sidewayfigure}
  }{}
}
\floatsetup{capposition=top,midcode=rule,}
\captionsetup*{
  figurename=FIGURE,tablename=TABLE,
  font={bf,sf},
  labelsep=period,
  justification=justified,
  footfont={sf,md,small},
  singlelinecheck=false}
\pretocmd{\floatfoot}{\rule{\hsize}{0.4pt}\vskip-0.75em}{}{}
\newcommand{\floatnote}[1]{\floatfoot{\textit{Note: }#1}}

\if@biblatex
  \RequirePackage{csquotes}
  \RequirePackage[natbib,style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\else
  \RequirePackage{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{chicago-apsr}
  \setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\fi
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\endinput
```

I put the cls file into the same folder where I have the template file. It compiles up to a certain point, when it asks me a font tile x1xtt.tfm. Although I try to install it, procedure is not successful (Unfortunately, the package txfonts could not be installed.). Hence, I downloaded the file from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/txfonts/tfm and put in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\public\newtx". Still the font file is not found and I end up without any pdf.

Is there any suggestion about? Thanks

Comment: Hi guys. I was able to fix the problem. I installed the package cm-super through Miktex package manager and now the file is compiling correctly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments